# How did they figure out the Eigenvector equation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346094/finding-the-eigenvalues-and-the-eigenvectors/3623127#3623127),
the person is unsure of what to do after deriving the polynomial equation (λ^3−λ^2)=(λ−1)λ^2. How did they get the equation in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of a square matrix $A$ is the result of computing the determinant
$$\operatorname{det}(A-\lambda I),$$
where $I$ is the identity with the same dimension as $A$. For more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial.

In this case, they computed:

$$
\operatorname{det}\ \begin{pmatrix}
1-\lambda & -1 & 1\\
-1 & 1-\lambda & -1\\
-1 & 1 & -1-\lambda
\end{pmatrix} = \lambda^2 (\lambda - 1).
$$